# Writing a helper method to use in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

From my readings looks like Helpers are for views.
The thing is that I want to pass some ugly hard coded JSON back to my view from the controller until my REST service gets ready. So I can just hard code it in the controller of course but was wondering if there is a cleaner way of not polluting the controller with that hard coded stuff and somehow writing it in a helper and calling that helper method in the controller instead.

So what do you suggest for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's data, you can create a dummy model for it instead:

```
# app/models/ugly_fugly.rb
class UglyFugly
  def self.fetch
    { foo: 'bar' }
  end

  # or if you want it as a string, you could do:
  { foo: 'bar' }.to_json
end
```

Then grab it in your controller:

```
def index
  @uglies = UglyFugly.fetch
end
```

And the best part is that this is easy to refactor, easy to hack together quickly, and still actually adheres to Rails-flavored MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your helper method in a new file and then just include this in your controller like so:

your_helper.rb

```
module YourHelper
  def json_code
    #logic
  end
end
```

your_controller.rb

```
class YouController < ApplicationController
  include YourHelper
end
```

Comment: And then your controller does the job of your model: retrieving data.

Comment: Yes true, coming from a dummy model indeed makes sense.